# How combine switch function with form option?

Tags: php, forms, input, switch-statement

I have

```
<?php
$favcolor="red";
switch ($favcolor)
{
case "red":
  echo "Your favorite color is red!";
  break;
case "blue":
  echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
  break;
case "green":
  echo "Your favorite color is green!";
  break;
default:
  echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, or green!";
}
```

What can i do for a insert what color i want in a box?
Or chose option from existent option, for whot me the message like your favorite color is...

Comment: very bad english, it is not clear to me what your question is :/

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach would be to use an HTML form and submit it using either POST or GET method. For instance, you might want to use an HTML `<select>` element to present a list of colors to choose from, or simply a text field input for the user to type their own favorite color.

Inside the script, you would need to check either `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending on which submit method you use in your form) to see if the form was submitted (usually by checking if the variable for the form's submit button is set). If it is set, you can simply pull the submitted form value for their favorite color out of the same superglobal variable (either `$_GET` or `$_POST`).

For instance, it might look something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["fav_color_submit"]))
    {
        //The form was submitted.

        $favcolor = $_GET["fav_color"];
        switch ($favcolor)
        {
        case "r":
          echo "Your favorite color is red!";
          break;
        case "b":
          echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
          break;
        case "g":
          echo "Your favorite color is green!";
          break;
        default:
          echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, or green!";
        }

    }
?>
        <form method='get' action='#'>
            <select name='fav_color'>
                <option value='r'>red</option>
                <option value='g'>green</option>
                <option value='b'>blue</option>
                <option value='o'>other</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type='submit' name='fav_color_submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```